# How to use the SingleChildScrollView() in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutterwebviewplugin

I'm trying to use the SingleChildScrollView() method to wrap a column to stop it from overflowing when the keyboard pops up but now the whole page is not rendering.
here's the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../widgets/text_field_input.dart';

class SignUpScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignUpScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SignUpScreenState createState() => _SignUpScreenState();
}

class _SignUpScreenState extends State<SignUpScreen> {
  final TextEditingController _emailcontroller = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passwordcontroller = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _usernamecontroller = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _biocontroller = TextEditingController();
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _emailcontroller.dispose();
    _passwordcontroller.dispose();
    _usernamecontroller.dispose();
    _biocontroller.dispose();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      // backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          // color: Colors.black,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32),
          width: double.infinity,


          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                //logo
                // SvgPicture.asset("assets/icon_oinkgram.svg",height: 64,color: Colors.pink.shade200,)
                Flexible(
                  child: Container(),
                  flex: 1,
                ),
                Image.asset(
                  "assets/logo_oinkgram1.png",
                  height: 32,
                ),
          
                const SizedBox(height: 32),
                Stack(
                  children: [
                    const CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 64,
                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                          "https://wallpapers.com/images/hd/waving-technoblade-anime-fan-art-xjz8fyxbzakvitgq.jpg"),
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      bottom: -15,
                      left :90,
                      child: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        icon: const Icon(
                          Icons.add_a_photo,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
          
                //EMAIL
                const SizedBox(height: 32),
                TextFieldInput(
                    textEditingController: _usernamecontroller,
                    hintText: "Enter a username",
                    textInputType: TextInputType.text),
          
                const SizedBox(height: 24),
          
                TextFieldInput(
                    textEditingController: _emailcontroller,
                    hintText: "Enter you Email",
                    textInputType: TextInputType.emailAddress),
          
                const SizedBox(height: 24),
          
                //PASSWORD
                TextFieldInput(
                    textEditingController: _passwordcontroller,
                    hintText: "Enter your password",
                    isPass: true,
                    textInputType: TextInputType.text),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 24,
                ),
          
                TextFieldInput(
                    textEditingController: _biocontroller,
                    hintText: "write a bio to express yourself",
                    textInputType: TextInputType.text),
          
                const SizedBox(height: 24),
          
                InkWell(
                  child: Container(
                    child: const Text("Sign up"),
                    width: double.infinity,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12),
                    decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                      ),
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 12,
                ),
                Flexible(
                  child: Container(),
                  flex: 1,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      child: const Text("Already have an account?"),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {},
                      child: Container(
                        child: const Text(
                          " Sign in",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.blue, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I keep getting errors along the lines:
RenderPhysicalModel object was given an infinite size during layout.

edit: 1 :
tried wrapping with expanded
returned the same errors:

[Errors image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWztB.png)

Any suggestions on what ought to be changed?

Comment: please wrap your SingleChildScrollView with Expanded

Comment: tried wrapping with expanded it did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SingleChildScrollView` takes in a child of a fixed height. You are using `Flexible` widget inside `Column` which doesn't have a fixed height. So, you can give `Container` a fixed height (`MediaQuery.of(context).size.height`) to fix the layout height equal to the device height. If the widget overflows this height, then it will automatically become scrollable.

Please go through this for detailed understanding of `SingleChildScrollView`
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html

Here is the code for your reference:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32),
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                //logo
                // SvgPicture.asset("assets/icon_oinkgram.svg",height: 64,color: Colors.pink.shade200,)
                Flexible(child: Container()),

                Column(
                  children: [
                    Image.asset(
                      "assets/logo_oinkgram1.png",
                      height: 32,
                    ),

                    const SizedBox(height: 32),
                    Stack(
                      children: [
                        const CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 64,
                          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                              "https://wallpapers.com/images/hd/waving-technoblade-anime-fan-art-xjz8fyxbzakvitgq.jpg"),
                        ),
                        Positioned(
                          bottom: -15,
                          left: 90,
                          child: IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {},
                            icon: const Icon(
                              Icons.add_a_photo,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),

                    //EMAIL
                    const SizedBox(height: 32),
                    TextFieldInput(
                        textEditingController: _usernamecontroller,
                        hintText: "Enter a username",
                        textInputType: TextInputType.text),

                    const SizedBox(height: 24),

                    TextFieldInput(
                        textEditingController: _emailcontroller,
                        hintText: "Enter you Email",
                        textInputType: TextInputType.emailAddress),

                    const SizedBox(height: 24),

                    //PASSWORD
                    TextFieldInput(
                        textEditingController: _passwordcontroller,
                        hintText: "Enter your password",
                        isPass: true,
                        textInputType: TextInputType.text),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 24,
                    ),

                    TextFieldInput(
                        textEditingController: _biocontroller,
                        hintText: "write a bio to express yourself",
                        textInputType: TextInputType.text),

                    const SizedBox(height: 24),

                    InkWell(
                      child: Container(
                        child: const Text("Sign up"),
                        width: double.infinity,
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12),
                        decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                          ),
                          color: Colors.blue,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 12,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Flexible(child: Container()),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      child: const Text("Already have an account?"),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {},
                      child: Container(
                        child: const Text(
                          " Sign in",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.blue, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Wrap the Column with SizedBox and give it height like this

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: SizedBox(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top,
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        // ...
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

***Output:***

[image: Output]

*Hope it will work*